# Netbeans Where is my Library JAR/Folder that I have added

Tags: java, netbeans

I have added a jar named `freetts` in Libraries in my Project, I copied the whole netbeans java project to another system but I could not compile it as the `freetts` library was missing there. So how do I locate the library on disk so that I can copy it to the system I have copied the project to.
[image]

Comment: I recommend to use a dependency management tool such as Maven.

Comment: Have a look at the online Maven book: http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the folder/JAR and click on `edit`

[image]

[image]

and in there you will be able to see where the folder/JAR is located on your disk